# Elm Http.post needs to produces Http.Request Int but send needs Http.Request String

Tags: elm

I decode response from Http.post request, where return type is **Integer**:

```
responseDecoder : Decoder Int
responseDecoder =
   field "data" (field "createDeadline" (field "id" int))
```

My problem is that I use Http.send  which needs **String**:

```
createDeadline value =
    Http.send Resolved (Http.post deadlineUrl (encodeBody value |> Http.jsonBody) responseDecoder)
```

And I dont know how to change the return type. My error message is following:

```
The 2nd argument to `send` is not what I expect:

113|     Http.send Resolved (Http.post deadlineUrl (encodeBody value |> Http.jsonBody) responseDecoder)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This `post` call produces:

    Http.Request Int

But `send` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    Http.Request String

Hint: I always figure out the argument types from left to right. If an argument
is acceptable, I assume it is “correct” and move on. So the problem may actually
be in one of the previous arguments!

Hint: Want to convert an Int into a String? Use the String.fromInt function!
```

Can anyone help with this? I'm just playing around with Elm, but I got stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem is that I use Http.send which needs String

According to the [docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#send), `send` function requires the argument to be of type `Request a`, where `a` can be any type (`Int` or `String` or something else).

The problem that you have is just what the hint in the compile error says:

> Hint: I always figure out the argument types from left to right. If an argument
>   is acceptable, I assume it is “correct” and move on. So the problem may actually
>   be in one of the previous arguments!

Thus, it seems that you've already defined somewhere, that you're expecting `String` and the compiler *infered* the type to `Request String`. For example, you might have the `Resolved` defined something like the following:

```
type Msg = Resolved (Result Http.Error String)
```

And the compiler inferred the polymorphic type of `send : (Result Error a -> msg) -> Request a -> Cmd msg` to something specific, because it already sees that the first argument is or type `(Result Error String -> msg)`:

```
send : (Result Error String -> msg) -> Request String -> Cmd msg
```

So, in this case the solution is either to change the expecting type:

```
type Msg = Resolved (Result Http.Error Int)
```

Or change the decoder and decode the response to `String`:

```
responseDecoder : Decoder String
responseDecoder =
   Json.Decode.map String.fromInt (field "data" (field "createDeadline" (field "id" int)))
```